# How to inject env variables AFTER the build process on a JS SPA

Tags: design

We have a build server that will transpile the JS source into the bundle file. I now need to inject values that are dependent on the environment the application is executed. The problem is, since the app is already bundled, I don't see a way of injecting it in a clean way.

Alternatives I've seen on other teams are creating another JS file, and let Chef replace that JS file at will. That JS file will then be included in the main HTML file in a second `<script>` tag. However this feels unclean, as it need to put the variables in the `window` object or something.

So what's a clean way to inject env variables in an already transpiled source code?

Comment: Environment variables are *not* code. It is quite okay to supply a parameter file after any compilation and building process has occurred.

Comment: What I feel smelly about this approach is that it will have to polute the global namespace, in order for the bundled app to be able to read them

Comment: Configuration files are inherently global. I believe the issue you are struggling with is that JSON files are often imported holus bolus: this is a bad thing. They have to be treated as properties files where you actively search and validate entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit old, but a solution we stumbled upon a few months ago is to run `sed` on the minified `.js` and replace tokens for the values we intended to inject.

```js
// config.js
export default Object.freeze({
  API_URL: 'MY_API_URL',
});
```

```sh
sed -i s|MY_API_URL|api.example.com|g app.min.js
```

Or something like that